# When will be A... p.p VS When will A be p.p

Tags: interrogatives

I'm confused between two interrogative sentences.

The first is "When will my score be updated?"
The second is "When will be my score be updated?
Which sentence is a gramatically correct sentence?

Also, I would be greatly appreciated if you give some extra related example sentences.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is incorrect. The word "be" is not a subject. In the correct sentence, "my score" is the subject being updated, not the verb "be". Examples: C = Correct, X = Incorrect

X: "Where should go my coat go?"

X: "Where should go my coat?"

C: "Where should my coat go?"

The two X's are wrong because the subject verb order is incorrect. If you have any more questions, just ask.
Have a good day!